# Applying filter to extract tweets on some hashtags from a particular country using python

Tags: python, twitter, location

I'm using the below python script to get tweets on #lockdownindia, #lockdownextension and #covid19 to get the tweets from my country (INDIA) and perform sentiment analysis. I've used cursor() from tweepy library to do so. When I use `#geocode:` it helps me out, but due to inaccurate radius, I'm getting tweets from neighboring countries like Pakistan as well, which I don't want. While reading [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/filtering-tweets-by-location#profile_locations), I came to know about `place_country:` but it is not working. It is returning empty dataframe. Any help on how to use `place_country:` will be appreciated.
Also, is it possible to get all the attributes of a tweet in a single go, as happens while using streaming API

```
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token = (access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

query = '#lockdownindia OR #lockdownextension OR #covid19 -filter:retweets AND place_country:IN'     #['-filter:retweets place_country:IN']        #geocode:20.5937,78.9629,910mi
max_tweets = 100

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, since = "2020-06-05", until = "2020-06-21",lang="en").items(max_tweets)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there I have checked the documentation and it seems like you are not supposed to put place-country in your query. It's one of the attributes you will be able to find in the JSON reply from Twitter. I suggest checking their JSON message under the place attribute for country and using a loop check if it's set to India.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So can you suggest me how can I get all the attributes of tweets in once, and get them stored in some json or csv file?

Comment: hey, I added another answer because I wanted to add blocks of code for you to use. Hope it helps you out

Answer (score 1):

Hey sorry I couldn't respond to this earlier. First off you'd want to import some libraries which are json, requests and time using the following line.

```
import json, requests, time
```

These should help you make http requests to the twitter api and manipulate the JSON response. Next you'd want to set your http request. I would suggest setting a variable for this. You can have it like this.

```
myrequest = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Atwitterdev&result_type=mixed&count=2'
```

Lastly you'd make the GET request to the twitter API. I am gonna save my request to the variable response.

```
response = requests.request(method = "GET", url = myrequest)
```

Now if you will have your response from the server. To access the JSON content of that response you need to use this command. I am gonna save my JSON content to the variable result.

```
result = json.loads(response.content)
```

Now you should have the JSON content and you can look inside of it just like you would've with a dictionary. I haven't used the twitter API before but I hope this helps. This is what I would use with other APIs.

Sidenote: Here is a [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) to how your http request should be from twitter. Best of Luck :)

Comment: Here's a guide I found online. It provides a more detailed explanation. [link here](https://benalexkeen.com/interacting-with-the-twitter-api-using-python/)